# How to convert std::array to boost::asio::buffer?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to convert an `std::array` to an `boost::asio::buffer` to use it for `async_read_some`, but I always get some errors:

Here is my code sample:

```
array<char, 16> data;
tcpSocket.async_read_some(buffer(data), [data](const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t amountOfBytes) {
if (ec) {
    cout << "Read failed with message: " << ec.message() << endl;
}
else {
    cout.write(data.data(), amountOfBytes);
}
});
```

This are the errors I get:

```
Error   C2661   'boost::asio::detail::buffer_sequence_adapter_base::init_native_buffer': no overloaded function takes 1 arguments
Error   C2440   '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'const boost::asio::const_buffers_1' to 'boost::asio::mutable_buffer'
```

I find it weird that all examples I see online use the same syntax.

Comment: This code compiles for me. Please provide mcv example, And remember that `data` when closure is called is not the same what array `data` which is passed when `async_read_some` is called because `data` is passed by value into lambda. What version of boost?

Comment: @rafix07 I am using Boost 1.69 with Visual Studio 2017

Comment: I am not that familliar with lambdas, can you exaplin why the type of "data" can be different inside lambda ?

Comment: You should update your question to MVC code. You are calling this code from free-function or member function? async_read_some expects mutable buffer, asio::buffer(data) can return const_buffer if data is const object, it is not your case, you defined `data` as non-const, so code should work. Your lambda takes `data` by value, so copy is made, `async_read_some` writes into data from function scope,  when handler is called, you are accessing copy of `data` array, it is not the same object what `data` in function scope. You can pass it by ref `[&data]`. It is deep topic, read about lambda capture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mutable_buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/mutable_buffer.html)

```
boost::asio::mutable_buffer buff( arr.data(), arr.size() );
```